# @MainActor + Combine inconsistent compiler error

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine, swift-concurrency

I have the following view model:

```
@MainActor
final class ProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {
  let authService: AuthService
  
  @Published var userHandle: String = "Unknown"
  
  nonisolated init(authService: AuthService, appState: AppState) {
    self.authService = authService
    appState.$userData
      .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
      .map {
        $0.user?.displayName ?? "Unknown"
      }
      .assign(to: &$userHandle)
  }
}
```

Which results in error: "Main actor-isolated property '$userHandle' cannot be used 'inout' from a non-isolated context", at the ".assign(to:)" line.

This is somewhat expected. As I understand it, Combine's dynamic thread switching doesn't satisfy compile-time guarantees of Swift's concurrency model.

Here's what's puzzling me. If I remove the @MainActor annotation from the class and apply it just to the userHandle property, like this:

```
final class ProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {
  let authService: AuthService
  
  @MainActor @Published var userHandle: String = "Unknown"
  
  nonisolated init(authService: AuthService, appState: AppState) {
    self.authService = authService
    appState.$userData
      .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
      .map {
        $0.user?.displayName ?? "Unknown"
      }
      .assign(to: &$userHandle)
  }
}
```

The code compiles without a problem.

Logically, this should raise the same error, since userHandle is Main actor-isolated in both cases. I was wondering if this is a compiler quirk or if there's a deeper semantic difference that I don't get.

Comment: The compiler uses a surprising bit of Voodoo magic when it comes to check whether the main thread is involved during the semantic analysis phase. It searches for the string literal "DispatchQueue.main" in order to come to a conclusion whether code is executed on the main thread, or not. Of course, this can lead to false positives and false negatives. See here the source:  https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/8d5cd5a47d6a01e9d65865482eb2984a2defac6f/lib/Sema/ConstraintSystem.cpp#L2023-L2025

Comment: Normally you would only use a Combine pipeline when you need an operator like `.combineLatest`  or `.zip`/`.merge` etc.

Comment: You could just remove the old `ObservableObject` and use `.task { userHandle = authService.fetchUser()` where authService is an `EnvironmentKey` struct and `fetchUser` is an async func that returns the user handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dispatch and Swift Concurrency is incompatible. During compile time, the compiler can only make a best effort to figure out whether code executes on the main thread when Dispatch is involved.

Anyway, I would suggest you refactor your class `ProfileViewModel` so that the class as a whole becomes MainActor isolated. *Optionally*, you may check whether you *actually* execute on the MainActor:

```
@MainActor
final class ProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let authService: AuthService
    
    @Published var userHandle: String = "Unknown"
    
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable!
  
    init(authService: AuthService, appState: AppState) {
        self.authService = authService
        cancellable = appState.$userData
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .map { $0 }
            .sink(receiveValue: { string in
                MainActor.assumeIsolated {   // <== Optional runtime check
                    self.userHandle = string
                }
        })
  }
}
```

Note, that when you change the queue to some other non-main queue, the compiler will not issue any errors or warnings!

So you might want to add this check at runtime:

`MainActor.assumeIsolated { ... }`

when your code executes within a dispatch block.